# In $\langle a, b\mid a^2, b^3, (ab)^2\rangle$, why does $ba=ab^2$?

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, group-presentation

### The Question:

> In $\langle a, b\mid a^2, b^3, (ab)^2\rangle$, why does $ba=ab^2$?

### My Attempt:

Clearly the presentation defines the group $\mathcal S_3$ under the isomorphism given by $\theta: a\mapsto (12), b\mapsto (123)$ and so
$$\begin{align}
\theta(ab^2)&=(12)(123)^2 \\
&=(23)(123) \\
&=(13) \\
&=(123)(12) \\
&=\theta(a)\theta(b) \\
&=\theta(ab),
\end{align}$$ but what would be a *word derivation* of $ba$ from $a^2, b^3, (ab)^2$?

Please help :)

Comment: e = (ab)^2 = a(ba)b, so by multiplying by a on the left we have a = a(ab)^2 = a^2(ba)b = (ba)b. now multiply by b^2 on the right to find ab^2 = ba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
 abab &= e \\
 a^2bab &= a \\
 bab &= a \\
 bab^3 &= ab^2 \\
 ba &= ab^2.
\end{align}